# Wordpress Tesseract Theme Responsive Changing CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, tesseract

I'm working on making a website using the Tesseract theme: thevandreasproject.com. In conjunction with a plugin I'm using called SiteOrigins PageBuilder, the responsivity does not work with the theme. PageBuilder does not work well with spacers plugin and margin controls in the GoogleFonts plugin which is what I used to make the website.

Through research I found a few other people with the same problem (see: https://siteorigin.com/thread/page-builder-background-image-wont-rescale-for-mobile-devices/) and basically you have to target each row with it's own custom CSS. I deleted the spacers and all the googlefont controls, but it still will not rescale correctly. On the Home page of the website Im using this CSS code to target the background image and the header text to position and size them correctly:

```
    @media (min-width: 680px) {
    .custom-home-background .textwidget .home-headline{
        margin-top: 40px;
        margin-bottom: 450px;
        font-size: 60px;
        font-family: 'Roboto';
        font-weight: 500;
        letter-spacing: 10px; 
     }
    }
```

It looks right on my PC screen but will not work on my iPhone screen. THe other problem is the button I'm using from the MangoButtons plugin. I have no clue how target that to size it correctly. It is also non-responsive. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: google media queries, min-width of 640 is more than likely more than a iphone

Comment: I've been playing with the min-width value and nothing works :(

Comment: this requires using detailed inspection using google chrome (right click and inspect element). I'd recommend learning css.

Comment: @David if you look at the link I provided above, there seems to be a way to fix it without learning the ins and outs of CSS. I get the gist of CSS basics but when I look at the elements on google chrome I have no clue what to look for. If you know a resource that could help, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/faster-htmlcss-workflow-with-chrome-developer-tools--webdesign-8314

Comment: Thanks! Is there something specific you could point out to me thats wrong on my webpage? That way I can get an idea what to be looking for in the elements and then learn how to fix

Comment: i dont see anything wrong on it, its more thinking about what way you want it to look than right or wrong, technically everything is correct unless you have a illegal value.

Comment: @David I am slowly figuring out how to solve the problems. I just have one last issue I need to fix on the website. It's the white space that appears in between my background image and the footer. It's only visible if you do element inspect and look at an iPhone 5 mobile view. What do you think is the problem here?

Comment: your div with the ID content has a height of 356px, its not in the css file so its either in the html output or added in by js.

Comment: @David I've been looking for hours to find this static height but for the life of me I can't. Where could it be?

Answer (score 1):

Welp after hours spent I've finally figured it out and also learned some CSS coding :)

```
@media (min-width: 680px) {
    .home-background .textwidget {
        font-size: 50px;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 500;
        letter-spacing: 8px;
        font-family: 'Roboto';
        min-height: 880px;
        padding-top: 20px;
    }   

}

@media (max-width: 679px) {
        .home-background .textwidget {
                padding-top: 20px;
                padding-bottom: 175px;
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 500;
                font-family: 'Roboto';

    }

.site-content {
        height: 0!important;
 }
#footer-banner {
   padding:50px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good! Now you can really start to make websites :)

Comment: Haha not yet! I ran into another problem. I posted another question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33703682/using-viewport-for-responsiveness-instead-of-media-queries

Wish me luck, thank you for all your help!