# Using viewport for responsiveness instead of media queries

Tags: css, wordpress, media-queries, viewport

My wordpress theme and the plugins I have installed conflict with one another forcing me to do my own CSS coding. After toying around with CSS and the inspect element tool on chrome, I fixed the responsiveness (not really fixed, more like hacked I guess..) of my website thevandreasproject.com. I used this code to make it work on the iPhone 5 screen:

```
@media (min-width: 680px) {
    .home-background .textwidget {
        font-size: 50px;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 500;
        letter-spacing: 8px;
        font-family: 'Roboto';
        min-height: 880px;
        padding-top: 20px;
    }   
}

@media (max-width: 679px) {
    .home-background .textwidget {
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 175px;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 500;
        font-family: 'Roboto';
    }

.site-content {
    height: 0!important;
    }
#footer-banner {
    padding:50px;
    }
}
```

I was wondering if anyone could help me figure out how to rescale my images and text correctly for ALL devices instead of having to figure out media queries for every device there is. I appreciate it!

Comment: yep google responsive design, basically you can use % widths/heights/margins or vw, e.g. `width: 100vw;`  should be the width of the screen. With text keep it px, otherwise it gets too small on small screens. But with most situations you should get away with 4/5 media queries for all devices with a small amount of rules if you switch to %. I use http://mobiletest.me/ to get different screen sizes, but basically media queries 400, 600, 800 and then 1000. It works out well 90% of the time. But read up on it, you need to define heights for parent containers for % height to work as expected etc

Comment: Thank you. Do you mind pointing out what is making the website not responsive? Also, why didn't the people who had the same problem as me (see link below) have to go about the solution the way I am?
https://siteorigin.com/thread/page-builder-background-image-wont-rescale-for-mobile-devices/

Comment: i suppose think of px as a measurement like cm, 20px is always the same size. However, 20% of the screen size will scale (make sure u have the viewport statement correct) and always remain 20% of the screen size. etc.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the smallest screen size imaginable then expand the viewport until it looks like crap. Put a breakpoint in. Repeat process until you reach largest screen size you want to accommodate. I think Dave Rupert said that somewhere. Anyways short answer is don't use media queries based on popular devices but instead based on your content. There is no easy answer.

Comment: Thank you. Do you mind pointing out what is making the website not responsive? Also, why didn't the people who had the same problem as me (see link below) have to go about the solution the way I am?
https://siteorigin.com/thread/page-builder-background-image-wont-rescale-for-mobile-devices/